# org-mode search in headline gives a three dots line

Tags: org-mode

certainly something I misunderstand, but I cannot find an answer.

When I search in an org-mode file (with C-s) and find a result in a headline, if I press TAB to expand the headline where I found text,
it expands but I get below a line with just "..." . This line is impossible to expand with TAB, and a part of the file is hidden... Where am I wrong ?

Below is an example file, I do

```
C-s
found
TAB
```

And I get this :

```
*** text 1.2...
**** text to be found

blu blu
...         <---------- impossible to expand with TAB, and rest of the file is hidden
```

Full example file :

```
* test

** title 1

*** text 1.1

bla bla

*** text 1.2

**** text to be found

blu blu

*** text 1.3

bli bli

** title 2

*** text 2.1

blo blo







Thanks,

Greg
```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to reproduce this behaviour only when the entire buffer was folded

For a more useful behaviour I'd recommend
**Two helpers:**

- **1)** Type <kbd>RET</kbd> and not a <kbd>TAB</kbd> in a search.

so:

```
C-s
found
<RET>
```

- **2)** use <kbd>Shift-TAB</kbd> (shift and tab) to fold and unfold

Comment: Thanks for your help.    
  
Yes, I forgot to mention it : I almost always start with the buffer entirely folded.   
  

Shift-TAB does cycle between "buffer entirely folded" and "buffer entirely expanded", so it's not very convenient for my problem...

Comment: Since all headings are hidden your search reveals only that heading and its children. In case of a heading that is the deepest in the hierarchy ( no children ) you get the ellipsis symbol . You can toggle the parent's visibility ('C-c C-u' followed by a `tab`), or toggle the entire buffer. If you wish to see the rest of the file, why not toggle/show it before the search?

Comment: I didn't knew C-c C-u, that is interesting. 

I am annoyed by this display, but this is maybe because of my usage of org mode : I have a unique HUGE file, I should maybe think about that.

Anyway thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: you should look at 'narrowing' as well as 'sparse-tree' functionality